# django simple captcha no such file /usr/share/dict/words

Tags: django, virtualenv, captcha, gunicorn

I am deploying my Django project on a virtual machine with Ubuntu Trusty.
To do this I am using Gunicorn (with Supervisor) and Nginx.

Here is the link to the tutorial I followed:
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

When I start Nginx and Gunicorn, the website is accessible, but when I try to reach a page that is using an app like django-simple-captcha, I get a "*Server Error (500)*".
As I am using **virtualenv**, all these apps (rosetta, easymode, simple-captcha...) installed with **pip** are stored in **myvirtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages**.

After some research, I modified my **wsgi.py** file to add the **site-packages** directory into the path, like this:

```
import os, sys, site

# Tell wsgi to add the Python site-packages to its path
site.addsitedir(os.path('/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

#activate_this = os.path('/webapps/project/bin/activate_this.py')
#execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
#sys.path.append(os.path('/webapps/project/'))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

... but it still doesn't work, knowing that if I uncomment one of the three lines above, I get an error message from gunicorn when restarting it:

```
project: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

Do you think the problem here is that I don't activate the virtualenv?
Should I find another way to activate it?
How can I have some more information about why gunicorn won't start with the `execfile` or `sys.path.append` line?
Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Please let me know if it lacks information, like the *gunicorn_start* script (even if it is the same as what we can found on many tutorials) :)

## UPDATE:

I didn't pay enough attention, the **gunicorn_start** script is activating the virtualenv, so I don't need to do it in the **wsgi.py** file.
But the problem is still here: I print **sys.path** in the wsgi.py file, and when I use the `python manage.py runserver my.server.address:8000` command, I can see that all the needed directories are in:

```
['/webapps/project/project', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/webapps/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

I can't figure out why I get `Server Error (500)` when I try to load a page that make use of `django-simple-captcha` app located in `/webapps/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I saw that it was only `django-simple-captcha` at the origin of the problem. And don't ask me why I didn't think to do that earlier, but I turned DEBUG on, and I got an IO error:
**no such file /usr/share/dict/words**

Indeed I was using

```
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = 'captcha.helpers.word_challenge'
```

in my `settings.py`...

Two solutions:

- Use another generator for `django-simple-captcha`: http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#generators-and-modifiers
- Install needed dictionnaries:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wamerican
  sudo apt-get install wfrench
  ...
  ```